# How to find efficiently the number of $3$-digit integers that are divisible by $7$ but do not contain the digit $7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried using a very time-consuming way, so I'm wondering how to solve this question in an efficient and organized way.

Comment: Describe your very time-consuming way? I don't know if any method I might suggest is more or less efficient than your method without having something to compare to.

Comment: My method is just a mess...I think any method suggested will be better.

Comment: outside of writing a script/code, I do not see an easy way

Comment: Sorting out how to use the divisibility rules $\pmod 7$ to accommodate the constraint seems harder and more error prone than a quick search. I'd just do the search.

Comment: Step 1: Calculate the number of integers up to $1000$ that are divisible by $7$. Step 2: Calculate the number of integers up to $100$ that are divisible by $7$. Step 3: For digits $a,b,c, a\neq 0$, $100a+10b+c\equiv 2a+3b+c \pmod{7}$. Using this, if $a=7$, we see that the number of 3-digit numbers starting with $7$ that are divisible by $7$ is the same as the number of integers up to $100$ that are divisible by $7$. Step 4: Enumerate all possibilities where $a\notin \{0,7\}$ and $2a+c \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$. Step 5: Enumerate all possibilities where $a\notin \{0,7\},b\neq 7, 3a+b\equiv 0\pmod{7}$

Comment: Step 6: Take the result from step 1 and subtract the results from steps 2 through 5.